Create Umbraco Package with Visual Studio
Visual Studio 17
Umbraco 13
I need to create a back-office API plugin for Umbraco.  This will be a new section and dashboard, with AngularJS controllers and server-side MVC content (well, not so much the view as that will be in the dashboard).  I see in VS, there is a template called 'Umbraco Package'.  Can I create an Umbraco package in VS that contains all these things and then just install it via the 'Packages' section?  Or do I need to do this the normal way of working with the Umbraco project itself and rebuilding the project and publishing and yadayada...?  If it is possible to do all this with a package, how does one go about that?  I'm not familiar with a "targets" file or anything else that goes along with Umbraco packages.
